# Which repository holds the Maven 2 Simian plugin?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, simian

Is there a Maven Simian plugin available for Maven 2.x? I can't seem to locate a repository which holds it.

The earliest mention I could find was an unreleased version at:

https://svn.codehaus.org/mojo/trunk/sandbox/simian-report-maven-plugin/

Perhaps I'm googling using the wrong terms...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077700/how-do-you-use-the-maven-simian-plugin-in-maven2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin Robert references is in fact a Maven 1 plugin, for details see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077700/how-do-you-use-the-maven-simian-plugin-in-maven2/1143077#1143077) to a related question. As far as I can make out there isn't actually a Simian plugin for Maven 2. Try PMD CPD instead (for details see the referenced answer above).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Guess we'll have to stick to CPD then; its just that Simian was producing better results.

Answer (score 1):

It's the the central repo - [search with nexus](http://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#nexus-search;simian).