# How do you use the maven-simian-plugin in Maven2?

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-1, simian

I'm looking for a Maven2 reporting plugin for [Simian](http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/) and the closest thing to such a reporting I found is [this](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/maven/maven-simian-plugin/1.6.1/). The problem is, the [documentation for it](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/simian/) appears to be for Maven 1 instead. Why is a Maven 1 plugin stored in a Maven 2 repository? I suppose that means I can use it... but how to use? The site mentions reporting but if I don't have a `src/main/site`, does that mean I can't use it? I was kinda hoping for something like `mvn simian:simian` similar to `mvn checkstyle:checkstyle` and `mvn pmd:pmd`. I don't want to generate site just for the reports. Sites take too long to generate when all I want is a quite xml report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Simian plugin listed on central is actually for Maven 1 (if you inspect the contents you'll see a project.xml and a plugin.jelly). So that explains why it doesn't work. This is rubbish and should be removed in my opinion.

As far as I can make out there isn't a publically available Maven 2 plugin, this may have something to do with the licence (Simian [isn't open source](http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/)).

As an alternative, have a look at PMD's [CPD plugin](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html), it may not be as fully featured as simian but I know it works in a Maven 2 build and detects copypasta pretty well.

To configure PMD, add something like the following to your POM:

```
<reporting>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Comment: Yea, I tried that already. Didn't work. I was hoping someone on stackoverflow actually uses Simian in their Maven projects.

Comment: I've had a look at the plugin and updated my answer to reflect it isn't a Maven 2 plugin.

Comment: Yea, there isn't a Maven2 plugin for Simian.